# Debug f# script file (fsx) in Visual Studio Code

Tags: f#, f#-interactive

Seems like a simple thing but I cannot find it anywhere online.
If you have any guide on debugging F# script file (fsx) in Visual Studio Code, please share, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that debugging of F# scripts (fsx) is currently not supported in VS Code, and unfortunately also not in Rider or the standard VS (which has a setting to enable it, but even then debugging does not work with .NET 6 fsi).

Check these github issues for more info (hopefully I did not misunderstand them):

- https://github.com/dotnet/fsharp/issues/12084
- https://github.com/dotnet/fsharp/issues/5457
- https://github.com/dotnet/fsharp/issues/9397
- https://github.com/dotnet/fsharp/pull/12722